# Double quotes within single quote string - NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, double-quotes, single-quotes

I'm having quite a problem to which other answers pose no solution.
I'm trying to print out double quotes in a string literal. I, however, keep getting errors.

This is the specific function:

```
app.put('/assignments/:name/assignee/:assignee', function (request, response) {
  logic.examine(request, function (mail, jobtitle) {
    if (mail !== request.params.assignee && jobtitle.indexOf('Personeel') === -1) {
      response.sendStatus(401);
    } else {
      logs_logic.addLog(mail + ' heeft gebruiker met naam "' + request.params.assignee + '" toegekend aan opdracht met als naam "' + request.params.name + '".');      
      response.status(200).json(logic.changeAssignee(request.params.name, request.params.assignee));
    }
  });
});
```

The error message reads 'Invalid or unexpected token' pointed to the part after the third 'plus' (or concat) sign. So it starts at "toegekend"

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you try using escape character?

Comment: You can use string literals instead of this. Check here for reference: http://brijeshbhakta.com/getting-started-with-es6#template-literals

Comment: Yes, to no avail. Removing the double quotes (so the string contains only single quotes) doesn't work either.

Comment: Use backticks for creating the string, I have explained in the answer below.

Comment: What is the context? My Chrome parses your code with no issues.

Answer (score 4):

use es6 template literas aka backticks which will create more clarity in statements.

```
`this is string ${some_variable} more text ${some_variable_2}`

logs_logic.addLog(`${mail} heeft gebruiker met naam " ${request.params.assignee} " toegekend aan opdracht met als naam " ${request.params.name} ".`);
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll accept the answer as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

Use backticks (`) to form the string instead of single quotes.

and use

```
${variable_name}
```

to use that variable in string.

Here is the example:

```
logs_logic.addLog(`${mail} heeft gebruiker met naam "${request.params.assignee}" toegekend aan opdracht met als naam "${request.params.name}".`);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Give the `&quot;` literal a try and see if it works for you. Something like this: `'This is &quot;quoted&quot;'`